# How to implement this simple association in jpa/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, associations

I have 2 test classes:

```
Class A{
   B b;
   // some other properties
}

Class B{
   // some properties
}
```

every instance of A has only one instance of class B, but an instance of class B can be assigned to more than one instance of class A

like :

```
B b = new B();
A a1 = new A();

a1.setB(b);

A a2 = new A();
a2.setB(b);
```

what type of association is this?
At first I  was thinking about a one-to-one unidirectional but maybe is a many-to-one? but I don't have any collection of A objects on B.

Can someone explain me what is the correct way to implements this association (using annotation)?

Comment: it is many-to-one from A's side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> every instance of A has only one instance of class B, but an instance
>   of class B can be assigned to more than one instance of class A

So , A to B is the many-to-one relationship . B to A is the one-to-many relationship.

The following shows the bi-directional mapping between A and B using annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tableA")
Class A{

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
   B b;

   // some other properties

}

@Entity
@Table(name="tableB")
Class B{

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
   List Set<A> listOfA= new ArrayList<A>();  

  // some other properties
}
```

Important points:

- `@Entity` marks the java class as an hibernate entity. It is mapped to the name of the table specified in the `@Table`
- If no `@Table` is specified ,by default ,  it is mapped to the table with the name that is equal to the  unqualified class name of the entity.
- `@ManyToOne` defines Class A to Class B 's relationship is many-to-one
- In the relational database , one-to-many relationship is expressed by using the following foreign key constraint :

  "Many side table" has a FK column which only accepts the PK of the "one side table".

  This  name of this FK column can be defined explictly by the `name` attribute of `@JoinColumn`. If `@JoinColumn` is not specified ,  then default value(s) with be used for this FK column , which  concatenates with the name of "one side table", _ (underscore), and the name of the PK in the "one side table".
- `@OneToMany` defines Class B to Class A 's relationship is one-to-many.

Comment: What i don't get is: i need listOfA on B class ?  in my example it doesn't exists, i have to add it to B class or i can just annotate B b on A with the @ManyToOne and no collection of A on B?

Comment: I just demo the *bi-directional* mapping between A and B. It means that given A , you can access B . And given B , you can access A.If you omit `@OneToMany` in B. , then their relationship is mapped as *unidirectional* .  Of course , it will also work!  But given B , you cannot access A

Answer (score 1):

The relationship is:

B (One) ---to--> A (Many)